# How to execute custom php/mysql code after a user successfully logs in?

Tags: joomla-3.4, plugin, login, plugin-events

After a user logs in, I want to call a little mysql program.

How and where (in what module eg. mod_login) do I place the code?

Comment: You'll need a plugin for this. Cannot be done with a module. See @johanpw's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onUserLogin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User) event, and create a plugin that runs your code when the user is successfully logged in.

In case you want to run it *before* the login is verified, you can use [onUserAuthenticate](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAuthenticate) instead.